# Regex to validate two digits with a space in between

Tags: java, regex

I want to validate the user input which should consist of two digits between 1 and 3 separated by a space. So far, the example `2 2` is matched.

Is my regex or the use I'm doing of it with `!sc.hasNext()` wrong to begin with?

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter Coordinates: ");
  while (!sc.hasNext("[1-3]\\s[1-3]")) {
      System.out.println("Please enter right coordinates!");
      sc.next();
  }
String userInput = sc.nextLine();
String[] stringCords = userInput.split(" ", 2);
for (int i = 0; i < stringCords.length; i++) {
     System.out.print("[" + stringCords[i] + "]" + " ");
}
int ycord = Integer.parseInt(stringCords[0]);
int xcord = Integer.parseInt(stringCords[1]);
```

For example, if I enter `1 1` I get this. Instead, I would like to validate it as correct and go on without being stuck in the loop.

```
1 1
Please enter right coordinates!
Please enter right coordinates!
```

Comment: Do you run into any problems or are you just asking for a review?

Comment: @Thomas i edited my question, it's not working as i wish. Thank You.

Comment: I'm not that a big expert on `Scanner` since I don't really use it but I'd just use `nextLine()` to get the input and then use `String.matches()` to check the input against a regex. Something like `String userInput; while(true) { userInput = sc.nextLine(); if( userInput.matches(regex) { break; } else {/*print message*/}`

Comment: @Thomas in that case what regex would you use? :)

Comment: The regex would still be the same as the rules wouldn't change, would they? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whitespace is the issue here, by default `Scanner` is splitting on whitespace which returns 2 values instead of one, change the default delimiter using `sc.useDelimiter("\n");` and it should work.

Here is the full code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    sc.useDelimiter("\\n");
    System.out.println("Enter Coordinates: ");
        while (!sc.hasNext("[1-3]\\s[1-3]")) {
            System.out.println("Please enter right coordinates!");
            sc.next();
        }
    String userInput = sc.nextLine();
    String[] stringCords = userInput.split(" ", 2); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Enter Coordinates: 
99 99
Please enter right coordinates!
10 10
Please enter right coordinates!
1
Please enter right coordinates!
1 3
[] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
 at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:662)
 at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
 at tictactoe.Main.main(Main.java:153)

Comment: I have edited my question with the full code

Comment: @Kaido [Code works fine](https://rextester.com/BFGUN43618).